# Error building JavaFXPorts project with Gradle 6.6.1

Tags: javafx, javafxports

Error Log:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

    A problem occurred configuring root project 'Mobile'.
    > Could not create task ':debug'.
       > Unnecessarily replacing a task that does not exist is not supported.  Use create() or register() directly instead.  You attempted to replace a task named 'debug', but there is no existing task with that name.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Anyway, heard something about it not supporting **newer** Gradle versions - if that is the case,  to which older version Gradle  should I downgrade?

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Mobile.Main'


dependencies {
    testImplementation     'junit:junit:4.13'
}
```

Comment: JavaFXPorts is EOL. It works with JDK 1.8, and Gradle 4 or 5. Use the Client plugin. Maven or Gradle supported (but up until 6.5 for now).

Comment: Java 8...? Guess, less things to learn then. Btw, thanks. I'll stick on Client plugin.